# Whats the best way to set height of datatables dynamically on window.resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have multiple tabs in my application with multiple datatables.

I am trying to figure out a way to adjust the height of datatables based on the screen size.

I tried the below function, but it doesnt seem to increase the height of datatable when the window is resized. Any suggestions would be very helpful?

```
  var calcDataTableHeight = function(percentageValue) {
             return $(window).height()*(percentageValue)/100;
         };



$(window).resize(function() {
          var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
                if ( table.length > 0 ) {
                    for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
                        $(table[i]).dataTable().css({ height: $(table[i]).dataTable().parent().height() });
                        $(table[i]).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();  
                    }
                }
                }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to increase the height using scrollY parameter..sample snippet below...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
    if (table.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            $(table[i]).dataTable().fnSettings().oScroll.sY = 
                $(window).height() < 650 ? calcDataTableHeight(40) : calcDataTableHeight(54);
            $(table[i]).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();  
        }
    }
});

function calcDataTableHeight(percentageValue) {
    return $(window).height()*(percentageValue)/100;
};
```

Comment: where's calcDataTableHeight?

Comment: var calcDataTableHeight = function(percentageValue) {
             return $(window).height()*(percentageValue)/100;
         };

Answer (score 0):

i used this and it worked

```
$(function(){
//set the main frame height on page load and page resize
    windowHeight = function windowHeight(){
        winHei = $(window).height()//window height without pixels
        $('div.clients-content').css('height', winHei - 130 + 'px');//dataTables container//130 is for my page design consider your own
        $('div.clients-content div.dataTables_scroll').css('height', winHei - 220 + 'px');//this is dataTable scroll container
        $('div.clients-content div.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', winHei - 250 + 'px');//this is dataTable scroll body
    };
    windowHeight();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        windowHeight();
    });
});
```